# How to detect Silverstripe page is loaded in Controller as parent or child

Tags: php, silverstripe

Our Silverstripe project has the following two page types:

```
class MultiSectionPage extends Page {
  private static $allowed_children = array(
    'Section'
  );

  public function PageSections() {
    $PageSections = Section::get()->filter(array('ParentID' => $this->ID));
    return $PageSections;
  }
}

class Section extends Page {
  public static $allowed_children = array();
  private static $show_in_sitetree = false;
}
```

In the Layout/MultiSectionPage.ss template the following code loops through each child Section as a dataobject:

```
<% loop $PageSections %>
<% include MultiSectionPage_Section %>
<% end_loop %>
```

I want to make sure that if anyone accidentally links to a Section it redirects to the parent MultiSectionPage.

```
class Section extends Page {
  public function Link() {
    return parent::Link() . '#section-' . $this->ID;
  }
}

class Section_Controller extends Page_Controller {

  public function init(){
    parent::init();

    if(!$this->getResponse()->isFinished() && $link = $this->Link()) {
        $this->redirect($link, 301);
        return;
    }
  }
}
```

However using this method triggers a redirect even when viewing the MultiSectionPage as the init must get called each time the Section DataObject is rendered.

How do I detect whether a Section Controller is being loaded as a standalone parent (redirect) or as child of a MultiSectionPage ?

Comment: The `Section_Controller` should not be getting called when you are viewing the `MultiSectionPage`. Only the `Section` object should be loaded when looping through `PageSections`. I'll give your code a test to try and recreate your issue when I have some time, but I'm fairly sure `MultiSectionPage` doesn't call `Section_Controller`.

Comment: @3dgoo - I thought this was the case as well, so I'm not sure why looking at the MultiSection page is triggering a re-drect. Will dig deeper.

Comment: What does your `MultiSectionPage_Section` template look like? And what does your `MultiSectionPage_Controller` look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Section_Controller` should not be getting called when viewing the `MultiSectionPage`. Only the `Section` object is loaded when looping through `PageSections`. When retrieving a `DataList` of `DataObjects` only their class is loaded, not their controller.

Note the `Section_Controller` should redirect to the parent page link, not the current page link. I would also recommend updating the `Section` `Link` function to return the parent link:

```
class Section extends Page {
    private static $allowed_children = array();
    private static $show_in_sitetree = false;

    public function Link($action = null) {
        return $this->Parent()->Link($action);
    }
}

class Section_Controller extends Page_Controller {
    public function init() {
        parent::init();

        return $this->redirect($this->Parent()->Link(), 301);
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing the link code to what you put worked. Which suggests it was a problem with how I was generating the links.